# Bootstrap3, navbar's icons position are changed as browser's wide is changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus .navbar-header>a:hover,
.navbar-header>a:focus {
  background-color: #7F613F;
}

.icon-color {
  color: #282828;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .nav>li {
    float: left
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #b39369; max-height: 50px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle navbar-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:#282828"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:#282828"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:#282828"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment icon-color"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt icon-color"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-color"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="max-width:360px;">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon-color"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see on the snippet, my code has navbar and icons in the navbar.

But when I make navbar or browser narrower, the icon `glyphicon-comment, glyphicon-list-alt, glyphicon-user` goes ugly.

I want these icons remain as if browser are enough wide.

Those icons are going left of the browser too much closely. I don't know why this happened.

How can I make these icons keep their position whatever browser's wide is.

Only searchbar and other something can be collapsed. 
But the other things should maintain their same position.

How can I make those icon are fixed on their position regardless of browser's wideness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have wrapped the contents within both a row and then also use columns to layout the contents within this row.

The below is now updated to include both of these and now offsets the negative margin at mobile viewports.

**More on Bootstrap grids here:**

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

```css
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus .navbar-header>a:hover, .navbar-header>a:focus {
  background-color: #7F613F;
}
.icon-color {
  color: #282828;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #b39369; max-height: 50px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle navbar-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:#282828"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:#282828"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:#282828"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment icon-color"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt icon-color"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-color"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="max-width:360px;">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon-color"></i></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Good answer